# In-game screenshot key on PC?

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-modern-warfare

Is there an in-game way to take screenshots? Or do we have to use external tools?

I don't see anything in the options regarding screenshots. Considering games released on the Steam platform typically let Steam handle screenshots, I would have hoped the Battle.net client would as well but I don't think it does. I suppose I could use the Xbox keyboard shortcut to take them (Alt-Win-PrintScreen) but it's technically not part of the game. Did they really not include this?

Comment: Have you tried the "default" screenshot keys like F10, F12 and PrintScreen?

Comment: Yeah, those don't do anything. F10 disables sounds, F12 and PrintScreen doesn't do anything as far as I can tell (except maybe the OS will pick up PrintScreen and copy to clipboard).

Comment: Does Fn+PrtSc work?

Comment: This question shows a remarkable lack of research effort, especially from someone who, with such a high rep, should know better what makes a good question or not.

Comment: @senpai how so? What is there to research? The game has come out only weeks ago. It's neither documented anywhere in-game nor a question anyone asked that I could find. For such a "basic" question, you'd think anyone would be able to point out where it is without a problem.

Comment: @senpai or are you implying that this question is not worthy of being asked or answered because it's not the kind of question that would be popular or memeworthy? Sure that may be the case but that doesn't disqualify it from being asked here. PC games typically come with a screenshot option, it would be out of the norm if a modern game today did not include it.

Comment: The OP is asking if there's an in-game screenshot key, not how to take a screenshot. There's a subtle difference between the two questions. The only way I could think to find the answer to such a question is to look at the keybinding settings, that said it's not unheard of to have actions in-game without editable keybindings. The question seems reasonable to me. The part about the battle.net client does appear to add to the confusion though and obscure the difference between the two questions.

Answer (score 1):

To automatically save a screenshot in windows:
<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScr</kbd>

This will save a screenshot in your pictures folder.

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't know about that one. Though I think for gaming, I would specifically want to use the shortcut from the Xbox game bar (Alt+Win+PrintScreen), at least with that it keeps screenshots restricted to the application (instead of the whole desktop in multi-monitor situations) and keeps all game related items together.

Comment: While a good answer, for someone like me with 2 monitors, `PrtScr` will capture the game window, and the full window of the other monitor.